# use of natlib changes interface of apalike references

Tags: bibtex, natbib, apa-style

So I am supposed to use `apalike` and cite using `\citep` and `\citet`. In order to use those two commands, I need to use the `natbib` package. However, this then changes how the table of referneces is displayed. It changes from *[author, year]* to *author, (year)*

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
    
    text \cite{hawking}
    %text \citep{hawking}.
    
    \bibliographystyle{apalike}
    \bibliography{sample}
\end{document}
```

**To see what I mean, just uncomment the two lines**

This is sample.bib:

```
@book{hawking,
          title     = "A Brief History of Time: From the {B}ig {B}ang to Black Holes",
          author    = "Stephen Hawking and Stephen Spielberg",
          year      = 1988,
          publisher = "Bantam",
          address   = "London",
          edition=3
        }
```

Comment: `[Author, Year]` is not how APA style looks, so the change you get is expected.

Comment: But thats what I get with the above LaTeX code

Comment: Right, but the output with `natbib` is the correct one. If you want something that looks like the output without `natbib` don't use `apalike`.

Comment: I completely agree with Alan. The output you get when you load `natbib` is the expected one. In fact if you don't load `natbib` (or any other citation-related package) you should be using `\bibliographystyle{apalike}` together with the helper package `\usepackage{apalike}`, which also makes sure that the "[Author, Year]" in the bibliography disappears. The output when you don't load `natbib` in the MWE is pretty redundant because it mentions the authors and year twice in quick succession. ...

Comment: ... It can also look quite uneven when the blocks in square brackets have different widths. Finally if you look at established author-year citation styles (like APA style, Chicago Style, ...) you will find that none of them repeat the citation label in the bibliography like this. (I wouldn't argue only from APA, because `apalike` is literally only "like APA" and does not [try to] implement modern APA requirements.)

Comment: Yes. I only use `natbib` so I can cite using `\citet` and `\citep`....can this be done without the use of `natbib`?

Comment: Theoretically, yes. Realistically, I don't think so. If you really must have the citation label repeated in the bibliography, your best bet might be to hack `natbib` to do that. But let me repeat what we said earlier: Neither `apalike` nor `natbib` were written with the intention of displaying the citation label in the bibliography and none of the established author-year styles does that either. So you may really want to reconsider your desiderata here.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the help.